# Navigation Properties not filled out by EF core - IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, identityserver4, eager-loading, ef-core-2.0

I have a case in which I need to be able to make all crud operations with IdentityServer 4 clients. It seems there isn't service for this so I am implementing my own.

The problem is that when I try to get all clients the navigation properties are not filled out for some reason. 
I am using eager loading like in the [ClientStore](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/73c87eeebd1fc0b5984e58c824dd5bc4def70ad9/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Stores/ClientStore.cs) implemented by the IdentityServer team.

So my method looks like this:

```
....
IList<Client> clients = _configurationDbContext.Clients
                .Include(x => x.ClientSecrets)
                .Include(x => x.RedirectUris)
                .Include(x => x.AllowedScopes)
                .Include(x => x.AllowedGrantTypes)
                .ToList();
....
```

I couldn't find anything special about their implementation, but the fact is the above code does not fill the navigation properties, but the ClientStore is working when I use it to find a client.

Does anyone have any idea why that may be?

**Update:**

In response to the comment from @Gert Arnold. This is the SQL that is being executed:

```
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime], [c].[AccessTokenLifetime], [c].[AccessTokenType], [c].[AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser], [c].[AllowOfflineAccess], [c].[AllowPlainTextPkce], [c].[AllowRememberConsent], [c].[AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken], [c].[AlwaysSendClientClaims], [c].[AuthorizationCodeLifetime], [c].[BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired], [c].[BackChannelLogoutUri], [c].[ClientClaimsPrefix], [c].[ClientId], [c].[ClientName], [c].[ClientUri], [c].[ConsentLifetime], [c].[Description], [c].[EnableLocalLogin], [c].[Enabled], [c].[FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired], [c].[FrontChannelLogoutUri], [c].[IdentityTokenLifetime], [c].[IncludeJwtId], [c].[LogoUri], [c].[PairWiseSubjectSalt], [c].[ProtocolType], [c].[RefreshTokenExpiration], [c].[RefreshTokenUsage], [c].[RequireClientSecret], [c].[RequireConsent], [c].[RequirePkce], [c].[SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime], [c].[UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh]
FROM [Clients] AS [c]
```

There aren't any joins as should be expected. I didn't provide more information because I don't have any or to be more precise, I can't think of anything that could help.

To me, it seems that it might be some configuration issue with EF core.

If you think of some piece of info that might be useful, please let me know and I will provide it.

**The entire debug log from the output window:**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:57919/admin/manageClientsAdmin/list application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 182
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Authentication was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method Nop.Plugin.Api.Controllers.Admin.ManageClientsAdminController.List (Nop.Plugin.Api) with arguments (Nop.Web.Framework.Kendoui.DataSourceRequest) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Information: Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'ConfigurationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Nop.Plugin.Api 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime], [c].[AccessTokenLifetime], [c].[AccessTokenType], [c].[AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser], [c].[AllowOfflineAccess], [c].[AllowPlainTextPkce], [c].[AllowRememberConsent], [c].[AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken], [c].[AlwaysSendClientClaims], [c].[AuthorizationCodeLifetime], [c].[BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired], [c].[BackChannelLogoutUri], [c].[ClientClaimsPrefix], [c].[ClientId], [c].[ClientName], [c].[ClientUri], [c].[ConsentLifetime], [c].[Description], [c].[EnableLocalLogin], [c].[Enabled], [c].[FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired], [c].[FrontChannelLogoutUri], [c].[IdentityTokenLifetime], [c].[IncludeJwtId], [c].[LogoUri], [c].[PairWiseSubjectSalt], [c].[ProtocolType], [c].[RefreshTokenExpiration], [c].[RefreshTokenUsage], [c].[RequireClientSecret], [c].[RequireConsent], [c].[RequirePkce], [c].[SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime], [c].[UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh]
FROM [Clients] AS [c]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor: Information: Executing JsonResult, writing value Nop.Web.Framework.Kendoui.DataSourceResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action Nop.Plugin.Api.Controllers.Admin.ManageClientsAdminController.List (Nop.Plugin.Api) in 14.0648ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request finished in 17.8712ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: We only see your `Include` statements. Where should we begin looking for reasons why they don't work as expected? For starters, did you check the executed SQL statements?

Comment: @GertArnold, Please check my update. :)

Comment: EF-core doesn't implement `Include` as one query but a series of queries. Is this really the only query that's executed?

Comment: Yep, I have added the entire debug log from the output window. If it is of any help...

Comment: You're gonna have to show the classes. We can only guess.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was busy. Today, after taking a fresh look at the things, I noticed that the Include extension method that I was using was not from EntityFramework core. That is why the eager loading did not work. :)